# Help me complete the following sentence

Tags: conditionals

**If it (to be)... warmer, we (to go)... swimming.**
I'm learning English and I can't distinguish between the types of conditional sentences. In that sentence, I am wondering between the 2nd and 3rd conditional sentences because I think each is reasonable, so can someone help me to complete and show me some tips to easily distinguish between types of conditional sentences, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both 2nd and 3rd conditionals work here! The only difference is the context.

- *If it were warmer, we would go swimming* : that could have happened as the speakers says this
- *If it had been warmer, we would have gone swimming* : same but it's in the past

Comment: So is there anything that is preferred or popular?